# Why json response not display.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I a getting undefined value while using ajax.I am using [http://validate.jsontest.com/?json={%22key%22:%22value%22}](http://validate.jsontest.com/?json=%7B%22key%22%3a%22value%22%7D)
I call like that in this fiddle.

I use post method in that I use only this url http://validate.jsontest.com/ **strong text**
http://jsfiddle.net/3TUvr/

```
var formData = {"key":"value"}; //Array 

$.ajax({
    url : "http://validate.jsontest.com/",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {                      
      alert(data["empty"]+"data");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert(jqXHR+"jqXHR");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try adding dataType to $.ajax request as dataType: 'json'.

Comment: I check setting dataType to 'json' doesn't affect. Please see my answer.

Comment: You have an error in your ajax call data passing format. url?json=formdata is proper format.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in angular2,

in my service I had code

```
   postJSON(){
        var json = JSON.stringify({var1:'test',var2:3});
        var params = 'json=' + json;

        var header =  new Headers();
        header.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return this._http.post('http://validate.jsontest.com', params, { headers: header }).map(res=>res.json());
    }
```

the problem with my code was that I forgot to import Headers.

```
   import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

`http://validate.jsontest.com/` does not contain any value other than `{"error": "You must pass JSON via the ?json= parameter to validate."}`.

If you change `data["empty"]` to `data["error"]` you will get the value `You must pass JSON via the ?json= parameter to validate.`. Your `ajax` request is retrieving the value in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out that the url you were passing is wrong:

Correct url : `http://validate.jsontest.com/?json={%22key%22:%22value%22}`

Updated [Js Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/3TUvr/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I tired your link and the json data is rendered properly,

You probably missed dataType: 'json' that is why you get 'undefined'

Your code should be like this,

var formData = {"key":"value"}; //Array

$.ajax({
    url : "http://validate.jsontest.com/",

```
type: "POST",

data : formData,

dataType : 'json',

success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

{

   alert(data["empty"]+"data");

},

error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

{
```

alert(jqXHR+"jqXHR");

```
}
```

});

Comment: I checked setting dataType to 'json' doesn't affected the result :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this API will want data in the form url?json= your json

So solution can be:

```
var formData = {"key":"value"}; //Array 

$.ajax({
    url : "http://validate.jsontest.com/",
    type: "POST",
    data : "json="+formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {


       alert(data["empty"]+"data");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
   alert(jqXHR+"jqXHR");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://validate.jsontest.com rejects POST requests unless `Content-Type` is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

The data attribute must be a string with Key/Value pairs(http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

So try using:

```
var formData = 'json={key:value}';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugocasalone/mfgbdLxo/